# Return records matching count criteria

Tags: ms-access

The query below returns grouped results based on a count :-

```
SELECT c.CUSTOMER_NAME, Count(q.DATE_QUOTE_REQUESTED) AS CountOfDATE_QUOTE_REQUESTED
FROM TBLQUOTESNEW q LEFT JOIN TBLCUSTOMERSNEW c ON q.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMERID
GROUP BY c.CUSTOMER_NAME
HAVING (((Count(q.DATE_QUOTE_REQUESTED))>4))
ORDER BY c.CUSTOMER_NAME;
```

How can I view the results ungrouped, but continuing to factor in the count criteria of >4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is just for returning customer table wihtout quotes... if you need quotes data also try joining this result with quotes table...

```
select * from TBLCUSTOMERSNEW cc where cc.CUSTOMER_NAME in 
 (SELECT c.CUSTOMER_NAME FROM TBLQUOTESNEW q LEFT JOIN TBLCUSTOMERSNEW c 
  ON q.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMERID
  GROUP BY c.CUSTOMER_NAME
  HAVING (((Count(q.DATE_QUOTE_REQUESTED))>4))
 )
order by cc.CUSTOMER_NAME;
```

Comment: I need to be able to view every record from TBLQUOTESNEW, not TBLCUSTOMERSNEW. How am i able to achieve this?

Comment: SELECT c.CUSTOMER_NAME FROM TBLQUOTESNEW q LEFT JOIN TBLCUSTOMERSNEW c 
  ON q.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMERID and c.CUSTOMER_NAME in 
 (SELECT c.CUSTOMER_NAME FROM TBLQUOTESNEW q LEFT JOIN TBLCUSTOMERSNEW c 
  ON q.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMERID
  GROUP BY c.CUSTOMER_NAME
  HAVING (((Count(q.DATE_QUOTE_REQUESTED))>4))
 )
order by c.CUSTOMER_NAME;